# VBA 3131 error in SQL using variables in query

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, variables, parameters

Can you please help me? I was trying to figure it out for about 2 hours but I still have some error in the syntax.

I have the following code with String variables which I need to pass into the SQL query in VBA script, but I am keep getting some syntax errors.

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "Delete * From " '" & [tableName] & "' & " Where (" '" & [tableFieldName] & "' & " = " & '" & [tableRecord] & "')"
```

Thank you very much for some advice.

Comment: First apostrophe is outside of text and thereby treated as comment. Of course if it would be inside of the string, then it would give syntax error also - table and field names should not be written inside apostrophes. And, if it is real SQL, then `delete` syntax doesn't include asterisk (*) - what kind of DBMS you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you were going for this:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "Delete From [" & TableName & "] Where [" & tableFieldName & "] = '" & tableRecord & "'"
```

Where I assume `TableName`, `tableFieldName` and `tableRecord` are variables??

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. TableName, tableFieldName and tableRecord are indeed variables, however I'm still getting the syntax error. Now it is the 3450 error.

Comment: Actually I changed my answer it wasn't quite right, I have no surrounded the TableName and the tableFieldName with square brackets `[]`

Comment: Also are you using Access here and not Excel?